# why the following regular expression does not work in tcl?

Tags: regex, tcl

I am reading some code in TCL, the regular expression does not work,

```
set name "Ronaldo"

proc GET_PLAYER_INFO {player_id {player_name "$name"}} {
    global name

    regexp "$player_name" "Ronaldo is awesome" match

    puts $match
}

GET_PLAYER_INFO {1,"$name"}
```

in this double quotation marks, "$player_name" is replaced by "$name"? and the $name is "Ronaldo", but why it does not match?

Comment: Does `regexp "$player_name.*" "Ronaldo is awesome" match` match?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, no, it does not match as well.

Comment: OK, I don't know Tcl at all so that was a shot in the dark. I expect that `regexp "Ronaldo" "Ronaldo is awesome" match` does match correctly?

Comment: yes, regexp "Ronaldo" "Ronaldo is awesome" matches correctly. but why the orginal one does not match?

Comment: No idea. Are you absolutely sure that the variable substitution actually happens before the regex engine starts interpreting `"$player_name"`? Because `$` means "end of string" in regex.

Comment: $ means "end of string" in regex? what does this mean?

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: You seem to be twisting yourself into knots trying to avoid the recommendations I made in http://stackoverflow.com/q/9736524/301832

Comment: @DonalFellows, yes, I am still twisting with it, seems like the way of calling this proc matters, if I call it like GET_PLAYER_INFO {1,"$name"}, it does not match, but if I call it like GET_PLAYER_INFO 1 "$name"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not doing what you expect. Curly brances means no variable substitution within them so when you call GET_PLAYER_INFO you are setting the first parameter to the exact byte sequence  contained within the braces ie: `1,"$name"`

Within the procedure, player_name is set to exactly `$name` so your regexp line expands to:

```
regexp '$name' "Ronaldo is awesome" match
```

So it attempts to match the end of line followed by 'name'.

If you want to use a variable default parameter you should really set it to some guard value then retrieve it from an external source when not modified eg:

```
proc proc GET_PLAYER_INFO {player_id {player_name ""}} {
    global name
    if {$player_name eq ""} { set player_name $name }
    regexp "$player_name" "Ronaldo is awesome" match
    puts $match
}
```

Re-read carefully [Tcl(1)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) paying special attention to the parts about grouping.

Comment: but if I keep the proc GET_PLAYER_INFO as unmodified, and call it like GET_PLAYER_INFO 1 "$name", it works, and the player_name is equal to "Ronaldo", is it true?

Comment: if we pass it like GET_PLAYER_INFO 1 "$name", the player_name is equal to "Ronaldo", and if we pass it like GET_PLAYER_INFO {1,"$name"}, the player_name is equal to "$name", how comes the difference?

Comment: Read this: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10259 and note section 6. No variable substitution will occur within {} grouping. Its rather like the unix shell single-quote.
You need to understand grouping in tcl or you will be forever surprised by how it works. Everything is a command with argument words. Grouping collects things into tcl words possibly performing substitution. Then the command that is the first word operates on its arguments. Depending on the command, it may run further substitutions (eg: eval or subst or proc bodies).

Comment: if I call it like GET_PLAYER_INFO 1 "$name", are there any difference with GET_PLAYER_INFO 1 $name?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to patthoyts solution I have another variant here:

```
set name "Ronaldo"

proc GET_PLAYER_INFO [list player_id [list player_name "$name"]] {
    regexp "$player_name" "Ronaldo is awesome" match
    puts $match
}

GET_PLAYER_INFO 1 $name
```

The `player_name` argument of `GET_PLAYER_INFO` will get it's default value from the `$name` variable (but take care: `$name` has to exist before procedure declaration).

Comment: The downside of this is that you are specifying the default value of the parameter from a variable when you parse the script. You might as well hard code it in and make it more readable. With this code, if the global name variable changes in the future, the default value used by this function will still be the original value. This is unlikely to be what was desired unless you are trying to define a closure function, in which case I'd expect a variable procedure name really.

Comment: Yes, that's true. In this variant the default value is fixed at procedure declaration time.