# Tcl: How to eval statements to fill in default args at call time

Tags: eval, tcl, default-value, argument-passing

How do you provide default arguments to a Tcl procedure that are evaluated at call-time?

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
> tclsh
% proc test { {def [expr 4 + 3]} } { puts $def }
too many fields in argument specifier "def [expr 4 + 3]"
% proc test { {def {[expr 4 + 3]}} } {puts $def}
% test
[expr 4 + 3]
% test 5
5
% proc test { {def {[expr 4 + 3]}} } {puts [$def]}
% test
invalid command name "[expr 4 + 3]"
% proc test { {def {[expr 4 + 3]}} } {puts [eval $def]}
% test
invalid command name "7"
```

The example is just to simplify code. Of course in this simple example one would just use `{def 7}` to set the proc's default value.

However, the goal is to be able to call some more complex function that delivers a good default value whenever the procedure `test` is being called. So the defaults can vary.

My current solution is to default to the empty string and check that:

```
% proc test { {def {}} }  {  if {$def == {}} { set def [expr 4 + 3] } ; puts $def }
% test
7
% test 5
5
```

However I consider this not elegant enough: There ought to be a way to put declarations where they belong: In the header.

Also, possibly, the empty string might be a perfectly fine value given by a caller that is not to be replaced with the default call.

Another workaround could be to just use `args` as a parameter and then inspect that one. But that provides even less explicit declarative style.

Any ideas how I can incorporate the eval into the declarative proc header?

(I'm on Tcl8.4 with no way to upgrade because of use in a commercial tool environment. But for the sake of this site I'd also encourage answers for more modern tcl versions)

Comment: The solution for 8.4 is just as valid for later versions; there's not been any significant change in this specific area in the past nearly 20 years (though best-practices _have_ changed over that time).

Comment: There's been a few questions about this topic recently.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9736524/7552

Comment: @Donald: I just learned about *args unrolling in tcl 8.5 a week ago, so I was suspecting or maybe hoping that maybe the declarative syntax has changed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one (which is just slightly different from your tries):

```
% proc test {{def {[expr 4+3]}}} {eval puts "$def"}
% test
7
% test 5
5
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, works. That was a permutation I obviously did not think of. Appreciate it! Will wait a day to see if there are other ways coming in, before checking as answer.

Comment: In my more complex real case I now do an explicit eval before using the argument (as the first statement(s) of the proc) with `eval set def "$def"`

Answer (score 2):

If you *know* that you'll only ever be passing in numbers, you can do this:

```
proc test {{def {4+3}}} {
    puts [expr $def]
}
```

**But this is unsafe** if you are handling general arguments. (If someone managed to pass “`[exit]`”, you'd notice!) Handling things *safely* requires more elaborate processing. If you can use a sentinel value like the empty string:

```
proc test {{def ""}} {
    if {[string equal $def ""]} {set def [expr 4+3]}
    puts $def
}
```

If you have no such sentinel possible, you have to either use the `args` special and do all the work yourself or you have to look at the length of the list returned by `info level 0`.

You *can* wrap `proc` with your own code to make this all simpler.

```
proc xproc {name arguments body} {
    for {set n [llength $arguments]} {[incr n -1] >= 0} {} {
        if {[llength [lindex $arguments $n]] > 1} {
            foreach {v def} [lindex $arguments $n] break
            set body "if {\[llength \[info level 0\]\] <= $n+1} {set $v \[expr $def\]};$body"
        }
    }
    proc $name $arguments $body
}
```

After that, you could just write this:

```
xproc test {{def {4+3}}} {
    puts $def
}
```

Comment: Love the mind boggling command mangling in xproc. Yeah, I'm stuck with arbitrary arguments. Excellent point, bringing up the security issue. I'm in a safe environment though, so it would be just an added feature to prevent people from accidentally [exit]ing or corrupting the tool's database

Comment: @cfi: Still better to avoid running through `[expr]` like that every time, as that forces recompilation of the expression each time and that's (relatively) slow.

Comment: And before you ask, `proc` itself can only use a value (i.e., a constant) for a default. You can compute the value at the time of definition of the procedure, but at that point it is constant (unless you redefine the procedure each time it changes, a trick I've seen used but not in performance-sensitive code). This stems from the fact that Tcl's values are semantically immutable; _they don't change_. This is a very subtle point.

Comment: I believe I didn't get your last comment. The constant here in this case would be the string describing some statement, wouldn't it? I'm ok with that in my use case. In my real-life case what I've used here as `[expr 4+3]` in fact is a call to a function implemented by a c-api. It doesn't even have any arguments. So, the function call is always the same. But the changing context anyway alters the data the c-api returns. The parsing of that command is ok to be slow, since the c-code's execution time is worse in O() and definitely to some great extent in the coefficients.

Comment: @cfi: Comments are not always 100% targeted at you. :-) The substance is that once you've defined a default value for a procedure argument, it can't be changed at all (not without tearing down and rebuilding the procedure from scratch, which is easy but very inefficient). This is a consequence of features of Tcl that run very deep (and the fact that `proc` is a pretty stupid command, which is usually good because it makes it preductable). That means that any runtime-determined default has to be done through code inside the procedure.

Comment: The comment about semantic immutability is one of the key distinguishing features of Tcl relative to languages like Perl, Python and Ruby (and C and Java and C++ and C# and Lisp and …). It's important because it impacts on the identity of values and on the expectations of code that works with them. But no way do I have space to write an essay on this here, and it's pretty off-topic for your question anyway. :-D